# How can I resize disk of virtual machine, using only the free vmware player?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, ubuntu-12.04

I have one of those [preinstalled virtual machines with Ubuntu system found at vmplanet](http://vmplanet.net/2012/10/ubuntu-12-10/). Everything is fine with it expect the fact the disc size(16GB) is often not enough, I looked in the settings of VMWare Player,

Can I resize disk of virtual machine, using only the free vmware player or other free vmware tools, and if yes how?

Eventualy can I create a  second virtual disk using vmware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) allows you to resize existing virtual machines drives.

Comment: Is it free for non-commercial usage ?

Comment: It is generally free (as in beer)

Comment: That means not as in freedom :p

Comment: Found a way to do that also with VMPlayer see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Found another way without the VMWare Converter and only using VMWare Player.

Make sure that the Virtual Machine is shutdown (not just suspended or hibernated).

Go to the virtual machine settings. 
Select the hard-disk and then click `Utilities` button -> `Expand...` .

[image]

Select new size the click `Expand`:

[image]

Comment: For those having trouble with a 'remove snapshot first' error, remove or rename the '.vmsd' file and try again.